# XAMARIN - Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.9 Fails

Tags: xamarin, uwp, visual-studio-2019

Last night, my mobile application ran fine.  This morning, I get a notice about a couple of packages that needed to be upgrade, so I take them.  Then, the application won't launch.  I get a failure:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

I traced the problem back to Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v6.2.9.  The real problem is that rolling it back doesn't fix the problem.  If I check the code out of GIT, it builds and runs.  If I upgrade all the packages, it crashes (as per above).  If I roll the upgraded packages back.  It still crashes.  The problem doesn't clear until I get a clean copy from version control.

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: 1) Do you have this nugget package installed-Win2D.uwp? 2) Do you have `<DisableWin2DPlatformCheck>true</DisableWin2DPlatformCheck>` in your csproj? 3) Do you have the latest version of Xamarin Forms? 4) When you Right click on the UWP project and go to Properties, and look at the application tab, what build does it say you're targeting?

Comment: 1.) I installed Win2D.uwp according to other posts I'd found.  No change. 2.) No, I didn't have that line in the csproj, but I didn't have that line there yesterday, either, when it worked. 3.) Yes. 4.) I tried both build 16299 and 18362.  No difference.

Comment: Hey I’m glad you figured it out man!

Comment: Thanks for your eyes on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting this out there for anyone who comes across any kind of similar bizarre error like this.  I pulled a version of the solution from GIT from three days ago. Compiled and ran fine.  So then I started grafting one file after another, one directory after another until I had moved every bit of source and metadata from the working solution to the broken solution.  It was still broken.

Finally, at 11:30 PM last night, I'm looking at the the diff of the two solutions and there are no source or metadata files that are different, but the new version still crashes!

**So then, exhausted and frustrated, I unhide all the files in the two solutions.  .git and .vs show up.  I delete the .vs directory and everything works again.**

Somehow Visual Studio corrupted the solution metadata causing a random runtime library resolution problem.  I'm never going to get those 12 hours back.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was the only thing that worked for me.